# What are the limits of using a ternary operator in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ternary-operator

The following Objective-C statement does not work correctly.

```
cell.templateTitle.text=[(NSDictionary*) [self.inSearchMode?self.templates:self.filteredTemplates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

However, if I split it into an `if()` statement it works fine.

```
if(self.inSearchMode){
  categorize=[(NSDictionary*)[self.filteredTemplates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"categorize"];
} else {
  categorize=[(NSDictionary*)[self.templates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"categorize"]; 
}
```

What are the limitations of using the ternary operator in Objective-C? In other languages like C# the above ternary statement would have worked correctly.

Comment: No error. Just that the result is nil.

Comment: The code is not the same. Both bits of code access exactly the opposite template. One of them is wrong, impossible to say which one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that it's an order of operations issue. Have you tried:

```
[(self.inSearchMode?self.templates:self.filteredTemplates) objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

(notice added parens)

Answer (score 8):

@cesarislaw is probably right about the order of operations.

However, the code will be more readable if you do something like this instead (and if you really insist on use of the ternary operator ;) ):

```
NSDictionary * templates = (NSDictionary *) (self.inSearchMode ? self.filteredTemplates : self.templates);

categorize = [[templates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"categorize"];
```

Comment: More readable, exactly as fast, and much better for debugging. If you want to see whether your templates dictionary was nil, just set a breakpoint. I'd add another statement for the result of objectAtIndex as well.